# Single-sign-on in Swing Java SE app and Windows AD based on logged user info

Tags: java, swing, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a web app.
In this web app there are user accounts stored in db. Passwords are not stored, users authenticate to Windows AD via LDAP.

I need to develop Windows tray notification app displaying some events that are happening in the web app. This tray app run from the client windows machine is supposed to send a request to the web app identifying itself as the web app user and display notification if web app response would provide some data.

1. I know how to write this tray app
2. I know how to handle and display the response from the web app
3. My concern is how to do the authentication in secure manner.

What I am thinking of is to verify on workstation level if user is logged in / authenticated into Active Directory. If it is true I would like to get the username and somehow securely inform my web that current user successfully logged in into AD and provide its username. Having that web app could send back response, if any is available for that particular user.

I am trying to avoid:
1. Requesting user for a password on app start if he has successfully logged into the AD.
2. Storing the password in any version (encrypted / hashed, etc) on the local machine, because it could be insecure and the password can change in the meantime.

Do you have any idea how to achieve the above or have other suggestion?
I will appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same requirement too, wherein I have a Swing-based desktop application that needs to be automatically authenticated when the user is logged into an Active Directory domain.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I did not. If you find something interesting, please don't forget to post some info here, I will appreciate that.

Comment: I finally end up creating separate password for tray messages. In the main app user generates strong password and copy that password to the tray notification system. The tray password allows to do some basic operations on system messages queue only.